# Typing a function that returns undefined if parameter is undefined

Tags: javascript, flowtype

Let's say I have this function [(try online)](https://flowtype.org/try/#0C4TwDgpgBAChBOBnA9gOygXigbyqghgLYQBcUiw8AlqgOZQC+AUAGYCuqAxsFWlLRGAA5IhAAUYMgH44SNAEppFanRxMoUKiyhiAhGHlqNG+ILbx0HACYQWNCFfWMoEADaJo2JybMWoYADoCYidmZiZONAooFnh8VABrMlkUdCxcYNIoAHIAMTjE7MYIqOA8UTJlGnosAWFRMVj4hPkgA):

```
type Person = { name: string }
function getName(p: ?Person): ?string {
  if (!p) {
    return p
  } else {
    return p.name
  }
}

const frank: Person = { name: 'Frank' }
/*
 * In order to work now, this has to have a maybe type
 * const name: ?string = getName(frank)
 * Even though I know it will is guaranteed to be a string
 */
const name: string = getName(frank)
```

I get an error, because Flow thinks that `getName` could return `undefined`. Though this happens only, if `p` would be undefined, which clearly is not the case.

Can I somehow type the function in a way, that the return type is `undefined` ONLY when the parameter is `undefined` and otherwise a string?

---

Edit:

Clarifying Example:
I have an easy function:

```
function getName(person) {
  if (! person) {
    return undefined
  } else {
    return person.name
  }
}

const maybeFrank: ?Person = getFrank()
const definitelyMaria: Person = getMaria()

const frankName: ?string = getName(maybeFrank)
const mariaName: string = getName(definitelyMaria)
```

I would like to type it in a way, so:

- If parameter is Just Person, return type is Just String
- If parameter is Maybe person, return type is Maybe String

Is that possible?

Comment: I guess the question would be, why not do `= frank && getName(frank)` to ensure that it is never `undefined` in the first place?

Comment: What do you mean? It would be the same.
`frank === undefined` => `frank && getName(frank) === undefined`!

Comment: Sorry, I could have phrased that better. My question is, can you change `getName` to not allow undefined? From what you've shown, there isn't much of a good reason to have it take `?Person`, and that signature is the core of your problem. If there is a case where `undefined` can sneak in, it'd be better to check that before calling `getName` with `undefined`.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. In my use case I unfortunately cannot do that without loosing all the static typing magic of flow.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean? Why would static typing be affected?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My opinion would be to remove the `?` from the function argument and leave the disambiguation up to the call site. e.g.

```
type Person = { name: string }

function getName(person: Person): string {
  return person.name
}

const maybeFrank: ?Person = Math.random() > 0.5 ? {name: 'Frank'} : undefined;
const definitelyMaria: Person = {name: 'Maria'};

const frankName: ?string = maybeFrank && getName(maybeFrank)
const mariaName: string = getName(definitelyMaria);
```

otherwise, if you really want to, you can explicitly redeclare the function with explicit types

```
type Person = { name: string }

declare function getName(p: Person): string;
declare function getName(p: void): void;
function getName(p: ?Person): ?string {
  if (!p) {
    return undefined
  } else {
    return p.name
  }
}

const frank: Person = { name: 'Frank' }
const name: string = getName(frank)
```

Comment: Your second solution worked very well! One more question, can I declare an arrow function like this? E.g., if I had `const getName = p => {}` instead of `function getName(p) {}`

Comment: That I'm not sure about, sorry.

Comment: Doesn't work for me, only `function` works, I think the `const` makes Flow really angry.

Answer (score 0):

I liked the solution by @loganfsmyth, but found it to involve too much typing for each selector.

I came up with a way to make this more generic, which saves you from creating multiple type signatures for each selector.

```
type FinderT<A, B, C> = (A, B) => C
declare function maybe<B, C>(cb: FinderT<number, B, C>, id: number, other: B): C
declare function maybe<B, C>(cb: FinderT<number, B, C>, id: ?number, other: B): void // eslint-disable-line no-redeclare
export function maybe(cb, id, other) { // eslint-disable-line no-redeclare
  if (!id) {
    return undefined
  } else {
    return cb(id, other)
  }
}
```

Usage:

```
maybe(findPerson, 42, state)
```

This correctly returns a `?Thing` or `Thing` based on whether the `id` is a `number` or a `?number`. Currently it only handles one extra argument, but this could probably be expanded to include more arguments.